# Is it possible to write a base class to handle nullReferenceException from all pages?

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, nullreferenceexception, base-class

I am using .net framework 4.0, plain asp.net and working with webform. Currently I having a base class to handle all parameter passing and redirect. I wonder is it possible to write a base class to handle nullRefeerenceException from all pages in once, lets say redirect end user to somewhere or display particular error message.

Scenario: For example, some pages must come along with parameter, if no parameter captured, I would like to redirect them to somewhere.

Comment: Redirecting to error pages are a bad idea. You should display errors in place with an appropriate error code (5xx in your case since it's a bug in the server)

Comment: There is also the important question which part of asp.net you're using. Plain asp.net, WebForms, Asp.net MVC, or some other framework?

Comment: @CodeInChaos I added in example ad

Comment: You still didn't say which framework you're using. Input validation in Asp.net MVC works very differently from WebForms, etc.

Comment: opps so sorry about that and updated again. I dun know this could be very important issue and cause difference. thanks for telling me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7469/discussion-between-smmr-a-and-codeinchaos)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to control the ProcessRequest. You need to test it to see if can do the work you ask for, but this is a good point to capture all errors of your page.

```
public override void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    try
    {
        base.ProcessRequest(context);
    }
    catch (Exception x)
    {
        // handle here your error from the page...
    }
}
```

### Some more notes

I was use this code on one critical page, but I do not use it for all my page. Even tho can capture the errors, some times you can not do nothing else here other than throw again the final error, so end up that is better to log your unknown and unhandled errors from `globa.asax` `Application_Error`, and on page make sure that you use `try/catch` to handle them where they happens.

After some think maybe is not good practice to use it. Good practice is to use try/catch in the place that you may have throws and not a general one like that.

### Last

You also get throw error here when the user close the connection before the end of the render, but if you log the errors you get the same on Application_Error - this is not a page error.

```
    Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> 
   System.Web.HttpException: The remote host closed the connection. 
   The error code is 0x80072746.
```

Comment: Great, this might be something I looking for! do you have any example?

Comment: Using a 3xx redirect is a bad idea. You should directly return an error code, and render an error page.

Comment: @SƲmmērAƥ This is the example ! and working code. I have used and its working good.

Comment: @CodeInChaos This is an example, you can do what ever you like. The idea is that I am answer, the point to capture the process of the page.

Comment: The problem with example code is that people will copy&paste it with minimal changes. So I try to avoid bad practices especially in example code.

Comment: nevertheless I hope to listen from both of you for any suggested solution.

Comment: @CodeInChaos Ok, I make it more general

Answer (score 2):

In you Global.asax, handle Application_Error.

Answer (score 1):

When a NullReferenceException is handled by the server a 500 response is created. Redirect all of your server 500 messages however you want. This guide will help.

[Definitive Guide to Handling 500 Errors in IIS6, IIS7, ASP.NET MVC3 with Custom Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198248/definitive-guide-to-handling-500-errors-in-iis6-iis7-asp-net-mvc3-with-custom)

Answer (score 0):

You can hook up to every uncatched NullReference Exception, depending on what you want to do.

For instance you can use the global.asax, to be specific the  Application_Error Event. You can get a reference to the exception, look for the type and perform a redirect there.

Another way to get ahold of exceptions would be to write your custom error provider, but that wouldn't give you the possibility to perform a redirect.